# Why do I get Class not found error in my Haxe OpenFL project when embedding external SWF library

Tags: haxe, nme

My OpenFL project is being compiled to Flash and another developer on the team built some components in Actionscript 3 for all the developers to use. I added the SWF containing the components to my build.xml file like so.

```
<library path="libs/Components.swf" />
```

I also added this to my build.hxml file in order to get code hinting in sublime text

```
-swf-lib libs/Components.swf
```

After adding an import statement in my Main.hx file I get the following error.

```
src/Main.hx:3: characters 7-43 : Class not found : com.companyname.components.Menu
```

I sent openfl the -verbose argument and was able to see the library being embed successfully and only got this error when I then tried to use the Menu class in the library.

Comment: I haven't tried SWF linking in Haxe, but the first thing I noticed was that you refer to 'GoNoodleComponents.swf' and 'Components.swf': are these separate SWFs or should the latter be 'GoNoodleComponents.swf'?

Comment: yeah that was my bad ... just a typo. Still having same issue.